# Tomcat dying silently on regular basis

Tags: tomcat

My tomcat (6.0.32, Java Sun 1.6.0_22-b04 on Ubuntu 10.04) keeps crashing multiple times daily without any specific output in catalina.out. This usually happens on high load (see top output).  **Update:** The pid-file is properly removed when this happens.

**Update 2:** No CATALINA_OPTS set, _JAVA_OPTS are:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m \
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 \
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 \
-XX:NewSize=10m \
-XX:MaxNewSize=10m \
-XX:SurvivorRatio=6 \
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 \
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
-Djava.awt.headless=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=37331 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=(myhostname) \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/java-6-sun/management/jmxremote.password \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/etc/java-6-sun/management/jmxremote.access"
```

Top:

```
top - 12:40:03 up 9 days, 12:15,  3 users,  load average: 30.00, 22.39, 21.91
Tasks:  89 total,   4 running,  85 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 53.2%us,  9.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 34.7%id,  1.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.8%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4194304k total,  3311304k used,   883000k free,        0k buffers
Swap:  4194304k total,        0k used,  4194304k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                       
25850 tomcat6   20   0 1981m 1.2g  11m S  161 29.6  11:41.56 java                                                                                          
12632 mysql     20   0  393m  97m 4452 S  141  2.4   1690:05 mysqld                                                                                        
14932 nobody    20   0  253m  44m 9152 R   56  1.1   3:26.57 php-cgi                                                                                       
 7011 nobody    20   0  241m  31m 9124 S   30  0.8   1:35.96 php-cgi                                                                                       
10093 nobody    20   0  228m  18m 8520 S   25  0.5   2:29.97 php-cgi                                                                                       
27071 nobody    20   0  237m  28m 8640 S   11  0.7   3:13.72 php-cgi                                                                                       
 3306 nobody    20   0  227m  16m 6736 R    7  0.4   2:29.83 php-cgi                                                                                       
 7756 nobody    20   0  261m  58m  15m R    5  1.4   2:22.33 php-cgi                                                                                       
 7129 www-data  20   0 3646m 7228 1896 S    2  0.2   0:36.65 nginx                                                                                         
 2657 nobody    20   0  228m  18m 8540 S    1  0.5   1:59.51 php-cgi                                                                                       
 7131 www-data  20   0 3645m 6464 1960 S    1  0.2   0:34.13 nginx                                                                                         
 7140 www-data  20   0 3652m  12m 1896 S    1  0.3   0:35.80 nginx                                                                                         
  619 nobody    20   0  231m  29m  15m S    0  0.7   2:33.46 php-cgi                                                                                       
16552 nobody    20   0  250m  41m 8784 S    0  1.0   2:48.12 php-cgi                                                                                       
17134 nobody    20   0  239m  37m  16m S    0  0.9   2:32.86 php-cgi                                                                                       
21004 nobody    20   0  243m  34m 8700 S    0  0.8   1:19.85 php-cgi                                                                                       
26105 root      20   0 19220 1392 1060 R    0  0.0   0:00.82 top                                                                                           
32430 nobody    20   0  256m  47m 9196 S    0  1.2   2:19.01 php-cgi                                                                                       
 314 nobody    20   0  256m  47m 8804 S    0  1.1   1:46.00 php-cgi                                                                                       
 2111 nobody    20   0  253m  44m 9196 S    0  1.1   3:01.14 php-cgi                                                                                       
 2142 root      20   0 26452 2564  868 S    0  0.1   0:00.56 screen                                                                                        
 2144 root      20   0 19484 2012 1368 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                          
 2333 nobody    20   0  249m  41m 9160 S    0  1.0   1:10.33 php-cgi                                                                                       
 2552 root      20   0 19484 2260 1620 S    0  0.1   0:00.01 bash                                                                                          
 2587 nobody    20   0  258m  49m 9192 S    0  1.2   2:04.50 php-cgi                                                                                       
 2684 root      20   0  4092  652  540 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 xvfb-run                                                                                      
 2696 root      20   0 60720  13m 2352 S    0  0.3   0:09.12 Xvfb                                                                                          
 2759 root      20   0  617m  12m 4676 S    0  0.3   0:00.66 node                                                                                          
 3514 nobody    20   0  270m  61m 9216 S    0  1.5   3:13.69 php-cgi                                                                                       
 5270 root      20   0 25164 1324 1036 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 screen                                                                                        
 5402 nobody    20   0  227m  16m 8032 S    0  0.4   1:33.61 php-cgi                                                                                       
 5765 root      20   0 81180 3820 3028 S    0  0.1   0:00.31 sshd                                                                                          
 5798 nobody    20   0  242m  32m 9124 S    0  0.8   1:52.08 php-cgi                                                                                       
 5856 root      20   0 19496 2292 1636 S    0  0.1   0:00.03 bash                                                                                          
 6442 root      20   0 62332  20m 1960 S    0  0.5   0:30.58 mrtg                                                                                          
 7082 root      20   0 88992 1916 1636 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 PassengerWatchd
```

I can't find any concrete reason for it, no Exceptions or messages of a shutdown in catalina.out (and no other logs in tomcat's log dir). I can start up the service and it will run for a few days or just minutes before dying again.

Is there somewhere else i could look for output? Could the kernel start killing threads due to a lack of ressources and by that bring the VM down?

Comment: Do you have other log files, e. g. application-specific ones for Tomcat and what do your system log files say (`/var/log/messages` and the likes)? Your `top` says that there's still memory available, so I do not think the kernel starts killing processes.

Comment: Are you by chance using the Oracle 11gR2 OCI JDBC driver?

Comment: I can't find any other output. There is nothing in the os-logs and my webapps haven't got any logs of their own.

Comment: @Corey: No, I am using MySQL, no Oracle server involved.

Comment: Can you post more details such as your CATALINA_OPTS or other JVM parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If the process is dying it could be:

1. JVM exited because of an unhandeled Java exception - you should see something in catalina.out or in the file used to redirect the STDOUT and STDERR - read as in application crash.
2. OS send a signal that was not trapped by JVM - you should see something in STDOUT or STDERR that are redirected usually to catalina.out- read as in JVM crash.

Find where the STDOUT and STDERR is logged:

```
sudo -u tomcat6 ls -l /proc/$(pgrep java)/fd/{1,2}
```

Analise the java exception. If you do not find it, then search for a JVM creash.

Enable core dumps: http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_enable_core-dumps

Analise the core: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/debugging.html#AEN1012

```
gdb /path.../java core
(gdb) bt
```

Analise the stack where JVM crashed.

EDIT: For high JVM load you can see which thread is generating the load. Use: `top -Hp $(pgrep java)` to find out the thread id that has the highest CPU usage. Then generate 2-3 thread dumps at 10 seconds apart with `pkill -3 java`. Convert to hex lowercase the PID of the thread from top output, then search for that number after `nid=` in catalina.out. That is the stack trace of the most expansive thread.

Also check if the JVM is not doing too much full GCs because the memory is not configured properly. See: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/GCPortal/, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-140837.html

Some useful tools: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html and https://visualvm.dev.java.net/

Comment: STDOUT and STDERR get logged to /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out, where I would expect it, but where nothing gets logged. This is really weird. I don't know how to apply the core dump activation for Fedora on my Ubuntu server; I see if I can find a howto for that.

Comment: Maybe they are rotated or overwritten at start-up time.

Comment: No, I can see the logs from the last start in it.

Comment: How it went with the core dump/gdb and with thread dumps?

Comment: I'm still going through the dump, but it looks as if most expansive thread was in GC, for at least 30secs (3 dumps after 10secs each). Also, I see a lot of threads saying: java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor) - does this mean anything to you?

Comment: If the GC is the most expansive one, then enable GC logging and see why. Ask the developers to take a look. If they have no clue, the you might need to do a heap dump. You can get a heap dump from the core or by asking JVM to do a heap dump. Please keep in mind htat the application might be frozen for a few minutes during the heap dump.The blocked threads are waiting for a lock. It could be the normal operation of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will kill processes if the OS is running out of memory(at the OS level, i.e. the current JVM heap size, not the used size)  If it were a standard JVM out of memory error then the process won't die, it will just stop doing meaningful work, and you would see the output in the catalina.out

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146152/something-keeps-killing-my-java-process-on-ubuntu-anyone-know-why for more info.